# Login failed for network user IIS

Tags: iis, sql-server-2016, database-administration

We have a classic ASP application with a SQL server 2016 database running on windows 2012 R2 and IIS.  The application works fine for myself and another two developers as we have administration privileges on the server etc.  But when other users click on the URL the index page opens and header shows but then states:

> Microsoft OLE DB provider for SQL Server error '80040e4d'
>
> Login failed for user 'domainname\usernetworkloginname'
>
> index.asp line 86

Line 86 is the third line of code below:

```vb
Dim objConnect
Set objConnect = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
objConnect.Open connection_STRING
```

The connection_STRING is in the location of Connections\connection.asp and is shown below

```
connection_STRING = "Provider=SQLOLEDB;Data 
Source=servername\databaseinstallname;Database=thedatabasename;User 
ID=;password=;Integrated Security=SSPI;"
```

The IIS application pool "identity" property is set to "ApplicationPoolIdentity" and I have setup Security permissions on the sites root folder for "IIS APPPOOL\thesitename".

I tried creating a login on the SQL Server (server level) for "IIS APPPOOL\thesitename" and in the logins "membership" I gave role membership of db_datareader and db_datawriter. But this does not seem to have worked.

My Database Administrator knowledge needs updating.  But how do I resolve this please?

Comment: You can't pass a Username and Password in the same connection string as declaring you are using a trusted connection. You either use a trusted connection or use SQL Authentication. What are you actually trying to use here?

Comment: @Larnu Thanks for prompt response.  The site in IIS is set for Windows authentication.  When I tried setting up a SQL server Login for IIS APPPOOL\thesitename I set this for Windows authentication but it did not resolve the problem

Comment: If you're using Windows Authentication, then there's no reason for the username and password to be in the connection string; they won't be used.

Comment: You shouldn't use AppPoolIdentity but a dedicate service account in AD.